# Visible Light Ground-Based Solar Observatory Data Archives?

Tags: the-sun, telescope, amateur-observing, data-analysis, observational-astronomy

I'm mainly searching for the best(or good/significant/important) solar data archives via ground-based telescopes. If I'm not being very straightforward...

Say if I wanted high quality/resolution images of the sun, I'd use SDO/SOHO's data archives-- they're easily accessible, queryable, and yield impressive images. So I'm looking for mainly visible spectrum images from ground-based telescopes rather than space observatories, although differing spectral images will be used just less-extensively. I've struggled to find any good data archives, however. NSO's archives seem all over the place, although the data it yields is impressive; so, if you are knowledgeable on how to recurringly access and reconstruct their data, I'd be much appreciative. Otherwise, is there any other ground-based observatories' archives that are freely available to the public, easily accessible, and present data online that anyone has used or know's about? Jpeg, png, etc. are all valuable, but if you know of any that use different file formats, they'd also be greatly appreciated.

Keep in mind, I'm not looking to discuss/argue what the BEST one is, but rather what commonly used/good ones are. So, any and all input will be greatly appreciated, as my project is best researched with many differing observatories.

Lastly, the better the telescope's quality in which the data is made available through, the better. So McMath-Pierce and other impressive unit's data should and will be given precedence over telescopes of less accuracy.

Comment: Here is one: http://www.bbso.njit.edu/Archive  Big Bear Archive